# The MySQL User table char passwords

Tags: mysql, string, char

Can someone shed some light on the `Password: Char(41)` column of the MySQL `Users` table? How do I convert a string to work in that column?

The passwords I see look nothing like the textual equivalents: `*2DA8242XXXXXXXXX` represents an 8 character password like `abcdefgh`.

Simply, **why** is the Char type used and **how** do I use it, as everywhere I have searched has provided a vague answer at best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the MySQL `PASSWORD()` function, e.g.

```
SELECT PASSWORD('mypassword')
```

(Security note: that clear text password will appear in the statement recorded in the mysql log.)

I think the best place to look for information about the password value stored in the mysql.users table is the MySQL Reference manual.

See:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/password-hashing.html